# How to secure my wcf service using AWS authentication

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, amazon-web-services, authorization

Can I secure my WCF service using AWS authentication. I am tring to figure this out by google search and finding articles on calling a service that is already secured using AWS authentication. Not an article of how to secure a WCF service with AWS. Isn't there an option, is my understanding of AWS authentication and signing wrong about this. Please point me to an article to start with.

Comment: To the sake of teaching how to (not) search for this kind of issue, we should publish the searches that do (not) worked to find answers to your problem!!

Comment: Are you talking about WCF SOAP services or WCF REST services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume your intend is to create a WCF REST service that uses [an HMAC based authentication scheme](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html) like [Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Welcome.html) is using.

The way to implement this is to create your own [`WebServiceHost`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webservicehost(v=vs.110).aspx) and override the [`ApplyConfiguration`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost.applyconfiguration(v=vs.110).aspx) method. In this method, you set a new `ServiceAuthorizationManager`.

```
this.Authorization.ServiceAuthorizationManager = new MyServiceAuthorizationManager();
```

Derive the `MyServiceAuthorizationManager` class from WCF's `ServiceAuthorizationManager` and override the [`CheckAccessCore`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceauthorizationmanager.checkaccesscore(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
class MyServiceAuthorizationManager : ServiceAuthorizationManager
{
    protected override bool CheckAccessCore(OperationContext operationContext)
    {
        // check the validity of the HMAC
        // return true if valid, false otherwise;
        return IsValidHMAC(WebOperationContext.Current);
    }
}
```

For more details on the implementation of the algorithm, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8366526/18044).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, sorry my bounty has expired, let me open a bounty again and try to award you the bounty points